# Split multi JSON value into multi rows C#

Tags: c#, json

I want to split a comma separated value, coming from JSON, to rows.
This

```
  ColA:X
  ColB:["1885331","2750160","151243","151241","2750159"]
```

To

```
  ColA:   X         X
  ColB:1885331   2750160 etc.
```

I tried to split it through Json Deserializer, but as much as I can understand the specific string isn't a list or an array. Can I split with c# ?

Comment: What do you mean by rows?

Comment: Can you please give a better example of your desired output? Do you want 5 of Pair<String, String> ?

Comment: Well what you posted isn't valid JSON and it's unclear what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I mean to split the multiple values of a field to values per row as the example. I don't know the exact number of the values, can be any number Post it's been modified , it looks better? From is a JSON and to is SQL server table

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
row.Split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Convert your input to a string and work through it like this.

```
 using (var sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var fields = line.Split(',');
                var test = fields[0].Trim();
             }
          }
```

Then you can create any type of object you want after.